# Updating the table with conditon problem

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

Using SQL Server 2005, VB.Net

In my application am using 3 textbox

```
Textbox1.text = Date
Textbox2.text = TimeIn
Textbox3.text = TimeOut
```

I want to update my table by using the textbox value with condtion

For Example

```
Textbox1.text = 23/02/2009
Textbox2.text = 10:00  - HH:mm
Textbox3.text = 18:00
```

Query

```
update table1 set TimeIn = '" & Textbox2.Text & "', NewDate = case when CAST(LEFT('" & Textbox2.Text & "', 2) AS INT)  > CAST(LEFT('" & Textbox3.Text & "', 2) AS INT) then '" & Textbox1.Text & "' + 1 else '" & Textbox1.Text & "' end, TimeOut = '" & Textbox3.Text & "'  Where Date = '" & Textbox1.Text & "'
```

The above query is showing error as "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '23/02/2009' to data type int"

Can any one give me a solution for this error.

Need Query Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to be using parameters rather than building the SQL statement using the string like your example, you don't want to fall victim to any SQL injection attacks.  *saftey warning over*   But that aside from that i thing :

```
`'" & Textbox1.Text & "' + 1 `
```

Should be

```
DATEADD(day, 1,'" & Textbox1.Text & "')
```

This will then add 1 day to your date